# How to express an object type whose values all have a certain type

Tags: typescript

Simple example:

```
type Bar = { x: number; y: boolean }
type Foo = { [key: string]: Bar }

const foo: Foo = {
  baz: { x: 3, y: true }
}

// This works fine
console.log(foo['baz'])

// Error: Property 'baz' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: { x: number; y: boolean; }; }'.
console.log(foo.baz)
```

I want the last line to type check and the type of `foo.baz` should be `Bar`. If index signatures are not the right way to make this sort of type, what is? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Index signatures are like a dictionary.  And to a access you need to use index. This is to make it clear at point of useage that a key not found is a valid possibility.

## fix

If you know the member is always going to be there annotate it as such e.g

```
type Foo = { [key: string]: Bar, baz:Bar }
```

Comment: The properties are arbitrary and unknown, all that is known is that their values are of some particular type.

Comment: Then you must use the string indexing as that is all that is declared

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have known properties then you can do:

```
interface Foo2 {
    baz: Bar;
}

const foo2: Foo2 = {
    baz: { x: 3, y: true }
}

console.log(foo2.baz); // fine
```

---

#### Edit

In the case that the properties are arbitrary you will have to use the type in your question and you won't be able to access the values as properties, because as you said, the keys are arbitrary and the compiler has no way of knowing if the property name you specified exists, for example you can have a typo and use `bar` instead of `baz` and the compiler won't be able to warn you about it.

Comment: The properties are arbitrary and unknown, all that is known is that their values are of some particular type.